# How I interpretate a CCA plot (made with xlstat)?

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation, causality, correspondence-analysis, xlstat

Here are the 2 CCA (Canonical Correspondence Analysis) plot I'm trying to interpretate. I did them using the appropriate function in xlstat.
[image]
[image]

I want to know how I should interpretate the fact that in the first CCA (Proteobacteria) "salinity" and "depth" vectors are located in II and III quadrant and are almost orthogonal one to the other.
In the second CCA "depth" and "salinity" are located respectively in I and II quadrant....Does this mean something?

Short and generalized question ca be: how I interpretate in a CCA

- The different length of variable vectors ?
- The angle between them and location of variable vectors (quadrant)?

Comment: what is xlstat?